# How can I create a context in preact?

Tags: preact

How can I create a context in preact?

like https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext in react

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preact supports the [legacy context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html) out of the box, but support for the new stable context API is still a work in progress -  there is a [pull request](https://github.com/developit/preact/pull/963) open on their GitHub to track this.

In the meantime, your options are to either use the old API or to use a third-party implementation of the new API like [preact-context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/preact-context).

Comment: FYI: The `createContext`-API will be included in our next major release. An alpha is scheduled to be published on March 4th 2019.

Disclaimer: I work on preact.

Comment: @marvinhagemeister: Excellent, thank you for the update :)